# Show category in menu blade laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, menu, categories, laravel-blade

I'm trying to show the categories in a drop down menu, but I'm having some trouble in the blade. The categories don't show, but I'm not getting an error.

This is my blade:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         PRODUCTEN
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/products">Alle producten</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"
          @foreach(\App\Category::all() as $cat)
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/cat/{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->categoryName }}</a>
          @endforeach
       </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an extra anchor tag, which  does not need here, try this :

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         PRODUCTEN
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/products">Alle producten</a>
          @foreach(\App\Category::all() as $cat)
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/cat/{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->categoryName }}</a>
          @endforeach
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to loop in anchor tag.
Just remove 1st line of loop and last  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

> ```
> <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
>         <a class="dropdown-item" href="/products">Alle producten</a>
>         
>           @foreach(\App\Category::all() as $cat)
>             <a class="dropdown-item" href="/cat/{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->categoryName }}</a>
>           @endforeach
>        
>     </div>
> ```